# Generate R.java and resource folders for java project

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

Is there a way to create/generate R.java and resource folders in a non-Android project, such as in Java?

Comment: gen and bin folders are automatically generated files. You don't need to generate it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great place to start looking would be into the aapt tool. This is the tool that creates the R.java class.

http://elinux.org/Android_aapt

Answer (score 0):

No,you can't create,R.java create automatically when you create a project.And when you make changes in your project,then it also regenerated automatically.